# Formatting and pretty printing dates with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date

I need to display dates in a couple different ways in an app built with jquery.

In some situations, I need the typical "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mma" type of formatting, with all of it's different permutations. In other cases, I need to show dates "pretty printed" similar to how StackOverflow does them:

- 5 seconds ago
- 12 minutes ago
- 3 hours ago
- yesterday
- 2 days ago

My application already uses JQuery UI DatePicker which includes a formatDate() function, but as far as I can tell, there is no way to use it outside of the datepicker. I want to format dates that aren't associated with a datepicker. Is it possible to do this using DatePicker?

The [DateJS](http://datejs.com/) library can parse dates like "12 minutes ago", but as far as I can tell, it cannot take a Date object and format strings like this. It can format the typical "yyyy-mm-dd" types of formats. This library seems pretty heavy as well.

John Resig's [Pretty Dates](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/) looks like it can provide the pretty printing ("2 hours ago"), but it doesn't do the standard formatting.

Is there not a single plugin that can do all of this? Is there a way to leverage the DatePicker code so I don't have to load multiple codebases that do the same things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://timeago.yarp.com/

Comment: @durilai: thanks, this looks nice. what do you do for regular date formatting then?

Comment: +1 Hosted at CDNJS, i10n, great community on GitHub and works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [prettyDate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-prettydate/).

It's made by the same guy that does the jQuery Validation plugin.

Comment: @alex: nice -- a better packaged version of resig's implementation. But what do you use for regular date formatting then ("yyyy-mm-dd")?