# Converting "2011-06-23T13:20:12+0000" to time ago

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

What is the "best" (and fastest) way to convert the date `2011-06-23T13:20:12+0000` into the following formats?

```
45 minutes ago
4 hours ago
2 days ago
5 weeks ago
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Formatting and pretty printing dates with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557672/formatting-and-pretty-printing-dates-with-jquery)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [jQuery.timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/), might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

John Resig to the [rescue](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this will be fast enough:

```
function daysAgo(dt) {
    var diff = Math.floor((new Date() - dt) / 86400000);
    if (diff === 1)       
    {
        return diff + ' day ago';
    } else {
        return diff + ' days ago';
    }
}

function minsAgo(dt) {
    var diff = Math.floor((new Date() - dt) / 60000);
    if (diff === 1)       
    {
        return diff + ' minute ago';
    } else {
        return diff + ' minutes ago';
    }
}

var then = new Date('2011-06-23T13:20:12+0000');
document.write(then + '<br />');
document.write(daysAgo(then) + '<br />');
document.write(minsAgo(then));
```

You can write the other functions for weeks and hours similarly. Also, these are approximations because of the `Math.floor` call, but I figured that would be good enough.